# Checking if some list values belong to another list

Tags: c#, list

I have two lists of words.

```
  List<string> mainList = new List<string> {"blue", "green", "mother", "black", "gray"};
  List<string> checkList = new List<string> {"mother", "green", "father", "black", "gray"};
```

Then I want to take a random element from the first list...

```
  Random rand = new Random();
  string iGenerated = mainList[rand.Next(mainList.Count)];
```

and then **check if this string also belongs to the second list**. I am not sure how exactly I can do it. I thought of smth like this... Is that the right way?

```
 if checkList.Contains(iGenerated) bool strInArray = true;
 else bool strInArray = false;
```

Comment: `I am not sure how exactly I must do it.` I know it. Try to write some code. if it doesn't work ask a specific question here showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: You would need to iterate over the second list, and compare each value in the second list to `iGenerated`. LINQ provides some extension methods to do this for you, but this is the fundamental operation you must carry out.

Comment: @GrantWinney It just turned out that I posted a question.. But then after some comments asking to show what I did already, I thought of some solution and it looks like a working one as you say.. Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're attempting to do can be achieved using the `Contains()` of the `List`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> mainList = new List<string> { "blue", "green", "mother", "black", "gray" };
        List<string> checkList = new List<string> { "mother", "green", "father", "black", "gray" };

        Random r = new Random();

        // Run five random tests
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            string mainListItem = mainList[r.Next(0, mainList.Count)];
            Console.WriteLine(checkList.Contains(mainListItem)
                              ? "{0} found in checkList"
                              : "{0} not found in checkList", mainListItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
green found in checkList
mother found in checkList
gray found in checkList
blue not found in checkList
mother found in checkList
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ey4shL)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my program in Console application:

```js
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<string> color1 = new List<string> { "blue", "green", "mother", "black", "gray" };
            List<string> color2 = new List<string> { "mother", "green", "father", "black", "gray" };

            string rd = GetRandom(color1);

            if (color2.Contains(rd))
            {
                // do something
                Console.WriteLine(rd);
            }
            else
            {
                // do another work
            }           

            Console.Read();
        }
        static string GetRandom(List<string> color)
        {
            var arr = color.ToArray();
            Random rd=new Random();

            int n = rd.Next(arr.Length);

            return arr[n];
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand that logic. But is there a way to do the same without rebuilding list into array?